# Drools 6.3 Custom Exception Handler

Tags: java, drools, kie

I have a Drools 6.3 project where I use kie-spring integration to define knowledge base inside spring application context. Using following code:

```
<kie:kmodule id="dar_module">
    <kie:kbase default="true" name="knowledgeBase" packages="drools,drools.queries" equalsBehavior="equality">
        <kie:ksession name="statefulSession" default="true" type="stateful">
        </kie:ksession>
    </kie:kbase>
</kie:kmodule>
```

However, what I cannot seem to achieve is to specify a custom *ConsequenceExceptionHandler*. In previous versions of the framework the kbase element had an element *configuration* that would allow developer to specify a custom handler. Like below:

```
<drools:configuration>
    <drools:consequenceExceptionHandler handler="cystomHandler" />
</drools:configuration>
```

But it seems like this option is no longer available.

1. Is there a simple way to achieve this?
2. Or was there a good reason behind removing this solution and I should rather not override the *ConsequenceExceptionHandler*?

The reason I ask for this is because I would like to continue an execution of rules even when an Exception occurs. I hope this is not against any Drools fundamentals.